# CreatePdf with xhtml2pdf from template and upload to S3

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

I tried to generate Pdf file from html using xhtml2pdf, after that I want to upload to S3. I had no idea how to do it, after trying a few ways but still stuck. Thank you so much for your help in advance.

```
def upload_pdf_S3(pdf):
    client = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key
    )
    try:
        client.upload_fileobj(pdf, 'test', 'test111.pdf')
        return True
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
        return False

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    upload_pdf_S3(pdf)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to upload the file directly to the S3 bucket without having to write it locally. I use a different upload function but the idea is the same:

```
def upload_pdf_S3(pdf):
   s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
   try:
     s3.Bucket(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME).put_object(
       Key=f"myfolder/myfile.pdf",
       Body=pdf)
     return True
   except:
     return False
```

The trick was that the `Body` parameter in `put_object` has to be in bytes format.

```
pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=response, link_callback=link_callback)
upload_success = upload_pdf_S3(result.getvalue())
    if not upload_success:
       return HttpResponse('File upload to S3 has failed.')
```

It didn't work for me using `pisa.pisaDocument()`, but it did with `pisa.createPDF()` and `result.getvalue()`, as the latter is the file in bytes.
In case you don't have a link_callback function, I used the same the [documentation](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-xhtml2pdf-in-django) has.

Comment: while OP question was clearly a shot in the dark, your response lacks some details: what is "response" in your 2nd example? And "result"?
EDIT: and why getvalue() works? why pisa.createPDF works instead of pisa.pisaDocument? 
If we can't understand this points it'll be another shot in the dark, perhaps it could work for you based on how you created "result" and "response? Perhaps "dest=response" is a typo and you meant to write "dest=result")? Who knows?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is in the same issues, you can tried this, it will create a local file, then you can upload to S3 for example.

```
file = open('test.pdf', "w+b")
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode('utf-8')), dest=file)
```